# How do I create a view that uses data from an external site

Tags: 7, views, services

I have a site that needs to get articles data from a view in site A in order to display these articles as a view in site B.

I found the module [Services Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views), which i don't completely understand.
I have installed it in site A, and created a services resource of a view with services display.

But how do I create a view in site B that displays the articles using that services endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [views_database_connector](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_database_connector) and include connection details to your settings.php and database will be available to views

add connection details to your settings.php

```
"example_db" = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'example',
      'username' => 'example_user',
      'password' => 'example_pass',
      'host' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

and when you create a view you can choose specific table from this database to connect to

Should work for both drupal 7 & 8

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 ways, Store the data in site B and not store the data

## By Storing the data

1. expose data from the site A.
2. Grab the data and store it in site B.
3. Display the data in site B.

To achieve (1) you can use many modules for this; I would suggest [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export)

For (2) You can use [Feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds), it will grab the data and import it.

For (3) You just create a view of the content you store.

## Without Storing the data

Use [Views Database Connector](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_database_connector)

Answer (score 0):

A view was intended to pull data from the site DB, so you can not just add a view to site B.

After you added a services resource to site A you need to add some client code on site B that would pull this data and display it to the user. You can either code it all by yourself or use, for instance, [Web Service Clients](https://www.drupal.org/project/clients).